# How to show/enable a button on ListView onItemLongClick

Tags: android, long-press

I have an Android application. In one of my Activities which is derived from `ListActivity`, I've implemented the `OnItemLongClickListener`. I want to enable a delete button within the relevant list item where the `ListItem` has been LongClicked. How can I do this?

```
    OnItemLongClickListener listener =  new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {
            Account a = null;
            a = (Account) av.getItemAtPosition(position);               
            Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "Long Clicked : " + a.getAccountName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //instead of the toast, I need to show/enable a button here...
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had a Button inside ListView's row layout then you can make it visible true`

```
OnItemLongClickListener listener =  new OnItemLongClickListener(){
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {
        Account a = null;
        a = (Account) av.getItemAtPosition(position);               
        v.findViewById(R.id.btnid).setVisiBility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};`
```

Comment: Hi Flavio, I just have a listview in my layout. How can I add a button to the listitem in my layout? Can you show me how the layout looks like after adding a button to listitem in listview?

Comment: You use one xml for list view's row. If you want to show one button inside a listview row when user click row. then you can take on button inside xml of ListView's row.

Comment: you should give a vote to answer to appreciate the answer.If it help you. And at last accept answer if anyone help you to solve your issue

Comment: I think I understood that I need to set the visibility of the button. But How I add the button to the ListView's listitem in the layout? At the moment I just have the ListView in my layout XML.

Comment: Are you using one layout for listview row..in this add one button. See this for more about listview http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/09/listview-example-in-android-with-image.html

Answer (score 3):

**.xml**

```
  <Button
  android:id="@+id/imgdelete"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

**.java**

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {     

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

       view.findViewById(R.id.imgdelete).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       return false;

 }            

});
```

Answer (score 2):

in your get view method of adapter set unique id to your button

```
btn.setId(position);
```

then on your click listener

```
OnItemLongClickListener listener =  new OnItemLongClickListener(){
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {    
    Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(position);
    btn.setEnabled(true);
}
};`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add boolean flag `isDeleteVisible` to `Account` with default `false` value.

Then in `OnItemLongClickListener` set it to true and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

In adapter's `getView` check `isDeleteVisible` and show or hide delete button.